# What is wrong with my MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote the following query for mySQL :

```
mysql> Create table R_Matrix 
       ( 
         image_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL REFERENCES Images(image_name), 
         Row INT, 
         Column INT, 
         Data INT, 
         PRIMARY KEY(image_name) 
       );
```

Where Images is a table in the same database and image_name is a column in it;

However I got the following error :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'Column INT, Data INT, PRIMARY KEY(image_name) )'
>   at line 1

I cannot find anything wrong with the query. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`COLUMN` is a reserved keyword. It must be escape using backtick,

```
Create table R_Matrix 
( 
    image_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL REFERENCES Images(image_name), 
    Row INT, 
    `Column` INT, 
    Data INT, 
    PRIMARY KEY(image_name) 
);
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: I would not advise using an ANSI SQL reserved word as a column name, even when enclosed in back ticks.

Comment: I didn't, used "Col" instead :) thanks.

Comment: using reserved keywords will give you pain in the neck in the future. `:D`

Answer (score 3):

The best option is to avoid using MySQL reserved words as identifiers.  Since you are running a `CREATE TABLE` statement, changing the column name is the best solution. (Choose a different column name; or at a minimum, add an underscore to the end of the identifier.)

The problem with your statement (as JW correctly points out), is that `COLUMN` is a MySQL reserved word.  Your statement is raising an error because MySQL is interpreting the token `Column` in your statement as a reserved word, rather than a column name; and, in that context, that reserved word is valid syntax.

A workaround (as JW also points out) to prevent MySQL as seeing that identifier as a reserved word is to enclose the identifier in backticks; alternatively, if sql_mode is set to ANSI, the identifier can be enclosed in double quotes.